# Fedora 32 wrong monitor resolution detected

Tags: fedora, monitors

I own a Lenovo v320 17IKB notebook. I installed a new monitor ( iiyama ProLite XUB3493WQSU-B1), which has a resolution of 3440x1440 but in my settings the maximal resolution I can choose is 2560x1440. `xrandr` outputs the following:

```
HDMI-1 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y
axis) 800mm x 345mm 2560x1440 59.95* 1720x1440 75.00 2048x1152 60.00
1920x1200 59.95 1920x1080 60.00 60.00 50.00 59.94 1920x1080i 60.00
50.00 59.94 1600x1200 60.00 1600x900 60.00 1280x1024 75.02 60.02 1280x800 59.91 1152x864 75.00 1280x720 60.00 50.00 59.94 1024x768
75.03 70.07 60.00 832x624 74.55 800x600 72.19 75.00 60.32 56.25 720x576 50.00 720x576i 50.00 720x480 60.00 59.94 720x480i 60.00 59.94
640x480 75.00 72.81 66.67 60.00 59.94 720x400 70.08
```

I don`t know the HDMI version yet. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't have a laptop or run Fedora these days, and I'm no expert, ..but I do have this same monitor and the same issue (albeit on Debian Buster).
I think the problem is that EDID data requires a sync rate higher than my computer can deliver at 3440x1440. The screen spec is from 48Hz to 75Hz. From reading around I see a lot of computers can only deliver in-range sync rates for this resolution via display port. I use HDMI. The proper answer is probably to do something clever with EDID settings, but that was beyond me.

My work-around started on xorg:

```
~$ cvt 3440 1440 44
```

(44 is the refresh rate I am using. I found that by trial and error. Start at something like 24 then work up - you have to go through the rest of the process below for each increment, to see if it works.)
cvt advises you the modeline to use in the next command, in my case I proceeded as follows:

```
~$ xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_44.00"  299.75  3440 3664 4024 4608  1440 1443 1453 1479 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 3440x1440_44.00
~$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 3440x1440_44.00
```

I put this in a script to run each time I logged in. I'm sure smarter people can make it permanent.

To then get the same refresh rate working on wayland:

- Login to wayland session
- Find device name:
  Devices can be seen in /sys/class/drm/
  e.g. card0-HDMI-A-1
  ( avail resolutions are listed in the modes file there )
  in the example the name is HDMI-A-1

So then at boot:

- press space-bar to get into manual mode, select your usual boot option but don't press enter, press e to edit instead.
- Then locate the section there that represents your usual boot option, and find the boot command there (probably ending in quiet). Type a
  space after that (to separate commands). Then type:  video=HDMI-A-1:3440x1440@44 (or whatever you worked out in your case)
- then press Ctrl-x to run with that option one time.

see if it works when you login to a wayland session

If it worked, make it permanent with something like:

```
su --c 'gedit /etc/default/grub'
```

Type at the end of the default linux entry within the quote marks:  video=HDMI-A-1:3440x1440@44

Then update grub with something like:

```
su - root update-grub
```

reboot -  it should now work.

As to whether running with this low sync rate is a good idea, that's another matter..

My background reading:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1137574/manually-add-a-resolution-to-gnome-with-wayland
- https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/kernel-boot-parameter-edit/